# Problem with adding dynamic width height

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

Original code is this one :

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, '50,30'); ?> alt="" border="0" />
```

What i had done is this :

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'.$image_width.",".$image_height.'"); ?> alt="" border="0" />
```

but it prompting me an error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single quotes are wrong

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'".$image_width.",".$image_height."'"); ?> alt="" border="0" />
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'$image_width,$image_height'"); ?> alt="" border="0" />
```

---

**EDIT**:
ok, if i'm not wrong this method resizes and adds watermark to a picture, therefore you were missing only one "

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'$image_width,$image_height'"); ?>" alt="" border="0" />
```

Comment: how about the second solution?

Comment: I don't know how your getSpecialLink is made. Your start with scr=", but you don't finish src with " at the end. So before you set width and height you need another " after the img url

Comment: You don't need to put variables in quoted strings at all. Try the simple `(int)$image_width.','.(int)$image_height`.

Comment: i just inspected and found that my variables data contains spaces :( "          100"

Comment: @clockworkgeek yes it did worked but just width is showing up rite, height is not coming what i defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'".$image_width.",".$image_height."'"); ?> alt="" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comma is not needed. On the first line your comma is here to separate to variables, not to show a string with a comma. In consequence your seconde line is wrong.

Try this.

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'.$image_width,$image_height.'"); ?> alt="" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->getSpecialLink($img, "'$image_width,$image_height'"); ?>" alt="" border="0" />
```